# Scientific Python 3 Updates

Tags: python, update

I want to use python 3 with the many scientific updates (numpy, etc.) on my new Raspberry Pi 3 (with latest Raspian). I followed some excellent advice from:

[Scientific Python for Raspberry Pi](http://geoffboeing.com/2016/03/scientific-python-raspberry-pi/)

EXCERPT:

> Step 6: Install the scientific Python stack
>
> Fortunately we can use apt-get to install all the massive, complex packages that make up the Python scientific stack without having to compile everything. This makes the process much, much faster.

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-matplotlib python-mpltoolkits.basemap python-scipy python-sklearn python-statsmodels python-pandas
```

> If you need a specific version of these packages or want a more up-to-date version than exists in the Debian repositories, you can use pip to install it, but be prepared for a slow compilation process.

That worked perfectly to upgrade python 2.7 but I want to use python 3.4 and upgrade that version.

Any ideas?
Mike

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Could you please be more specific about your problem? Did you install Python3.x and numpy etc using apt-get?

Comment: Here is a Google search that might help.  Looks like the first one might be right on point:  https://www.google.com/search?q=scientific+programming+for+python+3.4